# GET call with request body - request body not accessible at controller

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to do a get call with request body(JSON) as the request parameter list exceeds the limit. I am able to send the request via postman/insomnia and request is reaching till controller without any error. But the "requstBody" is empty at controller. What i am missing here?

```
@GET
@Path("\path")
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getResponse(String requestBody) throws IOException { }
```

When I replaced @GET with @POST, requestBody has value. For GET call do we need to add anything more?

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/4934937

Comment: @maio290 The link doesn't show how to get it resolved. It is sharing the ethics of passing request body in GET calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways for sending parameters in an Http `Get` method. `PathVariable` and `RequestParam`. In this way, sent parameters are visible in the request URL. for example:

```
www.sampleAddress.com/countries/{parameter1}/get-time?city=someValues
```

In the above request, `parameter1` is a path variable and `parameter2` is a request parameter. So an example of a valid URL would be:

```
www.sampleAddress.com/countries/Germany/get-time?city=berlin
```

To access these parameters in a java controller, you need to define a specific name for the parameters. For example the following controller will receive this type of requests:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/countries/{parameter1}/get-time", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public String getTimeOfCities(
    @PathVariable(value = "parameter1") String country,
    @RequestParam(value = "city") String city
){
    return "the method is not implemented yet";
}
```

You are able to send `RequestBody` through a `Get` request but it is not recommended according to [this](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/messages/9962) link.

> yes, you can send a body with GET, and no, it is never useful
>   to do so.

This elaboration in [elasticsearch website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_empty_search.html) is nice too:

> The HTTP libraries of certain languages (notably JavaScript) don’t allow GET requests to have a request body. In fact, some users are suprised that GET requests are ever allowed to have a body.
>
> The truth is that RFC 7231—the RFC that deals with HTTP semantics and
>   content—does not define what should happen to a GET request with a
>   body! As a result, some HTTP servers allow it, and some—especially
>   caching proxies—don’t.

If you want to use `Post` method, you are able to have `RequestBody` too. In the case you want to send data by a post request, an appropriate controller would be like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/countries/{parameter1}/get-time", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public String getTimeOfCitiesByPost(
        @PathVariable(value = "parameter1") String country,
        @RequestParam(value = "city") String city,
        @RequestBody Object myCustomObject

){
    return "the method is not implemented yet";
}
```

`myCustomObject` could have any type of data you defined in your code. Note that in this way, you should send request body as a `Json` string.

Comment: you can send body with GET method too, but it's ignored for most cases.

Comment: @hamid from some other links, I can see, via GET call we can pass RequestBody too. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/4934937

Comment: @MuratGüvenç This is not a standard way and I suggest to prevent that.

Comment: absolutely it is not a standard or advised way. Prevent this kind of API design if possible.

Comment: @vineeth I have added an important part of the link you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Some HTTP servers allow it, and some—especially caching proxies—don’t. We tried a POC with Tomcat on which we passed the requestBody successfully. But when we tried the same with Weblogic( which is a caching proxies server), we were not able to succeed.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to do a get call with request body(JSON) as the request parameter list exceeds the limit. I am able to send the request via postman/insomnia and request is reaching till controller without any error. But the "requstBody" is empty at controller. What i am missing here?

One thing you are missing is the fact that the semantics of a request body with GET are not well defined.

[RFC 7231, Section 4.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1):

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

Comment: By rejecting request you meant rejecting requestBody right? Because I am able to hit the my controller with the request but the requestBody is empty

Comment: @vineeth to quote from the old c++ standards newsgroup: "not defined" = "could make demons fly out of your nose". So any action the server or framework takes would be seen as ok. Be it rejecting the request, ignoring the body or using the body.

Answer (score 2):

put `@RequestBody` on `String requestBody` parameter

Comment: I can actually confirm that this is working with springBoot 2.1.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 2):

```
@RequestMapping("/path/{requestBody}")
public Response getResponse(@PathVariable String requestBody) throws IOException { }
```

Comment: It would be nice to add some details to this code. Why those annotation ?

Comment: @mkjh my requirement is pass the details in requestBody rather than requestParameter/PathVariable

Comment: @vineeth but requestbody is for POST. You should be using Uri for GET request

Comment: @mkjh See the link provided by maio290 above. GET calls too supports body